# NPE was thrown loading key/value pairs into java.util.Properties object

Tags: java, properties

I ran into a question that I was having trouble to answer for myself in regards to loading key/value pairs into a java.util.Properties object from stream. There is a method invokes loadProperties() method in a Foo servlet class I was working on. In the case 1) retrieving value for a selected key worked however in the case 2) loadProperties().getProperty("bar") threw NullPointerException. I am not sure why NPE was thrown. I forgot to add but loadProperties() called multiple times within same instance of Foo.

case 1)

```
public class Foo extends HttpServlet {
    private InputStream is = null;

    private Properties loadProperties() {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        is = Foo.class.getClassLoader().getResourceStream("/com/test/bar.properties");
        p.load(is);
        return p;
    }
}
```

case 2)

```
public class Foo extends HttpServlet {
    private final InputStream is = Foo.class.getClassLoader().getResourceStream("/com/test/bar.properties);

    private Properties loadProperties() {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(is);
        return p;
    }
}
```

Invoking loadProperties()

```
public class Foo extends HttpServlet {
    private Properties loadProperties() { .... }

    private void doSomething() {
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(loadProperties().getProperty("bar"))); // NPE was thrown in the case 2)
        is.close();
    }

    private void doSomething2() {
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(loadProperties().getProperty("xyz")));
        is.close();
    }
}
```

[update]

Andy answered my question. When he asked me if loadProperties() called more than once I inspected long lines of Foo class and alas! I found out that it was called once within doPost method inadvertently.

```
public class Foo extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(...) {
        loadProperties();

        callDoSomething();
        callDoSomething2();
    }

    private Properties loadPropeties() {
        ....
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        ....
    }

    private void doSomething2() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the NPE thrown? In loadProperties or doSomething?

Comment: @Andy: when I debugged the program, loadProperties().getProperty("bar") returns null

Comment: Are you invoking `loadProperties` more than once on the same instance of `Foo`? The stream would be exhausted after the first invocation in case 2, whereas it would be created fresh each time in case 1.

Comment: Yes. there are more than one method invokes loadProperties for retrieving different value mapped to different key however I closed the stream in each case by calling is.close().

Comment: Well then it's unsurprising that you aren't reading anything - you can't read from a closed stream, nor can you reopen it. Note that you're not actually showing the `is.close()` call in your question; you need to include all pertinent details to get a good answer.

Comment: @Andy: Would you mind explaining to me why it would be exhausted after the first invocation in case 2? Thank you!

Comment: will update my question by adding is.close();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88048/discussion-between-daeyoung-and-andy-turner).

Comment: *"Would you mind explaining to me why it would be exhausted"* -- because you read all of the characters in the `is` stream the first time you called `p.load(is)`.  The `Properties.load` method is not going to reset the stream to the start.  For a start, it can't!

Comment: @Stephen C: Thanks for your answer. Now I know why. As I updated my question I called loadProperties inadvertently once before any of doSomething or doSomething2 was called. That is why the program reaches one of the methods, stream is already closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case 2, you are attempting to re-use the same stream each time you invoke the `loadProperties` method.

This *might* work correctly on the first invocation: `Properties.load` will consume all the data in the stream until it reaches the end, and then gives you back all of the `Property`s that it loaded.

(The "*might*" is because of the thread safety issue mentioned below).

However, on subsequent invocations of `loadProperties()` (case 2), there is nothing more to read - all of the data in the stream has been consumed. Unless you explicitly rewind the stream (which you may not even be able to do, depending upon the specific subclass of `InputStream` returned), you won't have any more data to read.

There is another problem in case 2, however, meaning that you should not attempt to rewind the stream: it is not thread safe. If two threads attempt to invoke `loadProperties()` at the same time, I wouldn't like to guess what would happen. You'd likely just get nonsense out.

The Javadoc for `Properties.load(InputStream)` doesn't say anything about the method synchronizing on the passed `InputStream`. As such, you should avoid getting into the situation of having thread-unsafe code - and you do in case 1, by creating a new `InputStream` for each invocation.

I assume that you are attempting to avoid re-reading the properties multiple times. I would recommend loading the `Properties` outside your class and injecting them as a constructor parameter:

```
class Foo extends HttpServlet {
  private final Properties properties;

  Foo(Properties properties) {
    this.properties = checkNotNull(properties);
  }

  private void doSomething() {
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(properties.getProperty("bar")));
    // ...
}
```

This way, if you have an instance of `Foo`, it has valid `Properties`; you aren't waiting for a particular code path to be executed which will trigger the loading of properties, and have that loading fail.

It also makes the code easier to test - you are no longer reliant on the properties being loaded from a file - it can come from anywhere.

Comment: One more thing. You are right saying case 2) might work once. After removing offending call of loadProperties() within doPost. Invoking loadPropeties() from doSomething method worked but not in doSomething2 method when I sequentially called each method from a client.